# Returning Entire Array As String

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an array that is populated if a formula produces an "X" in a cell that is part of a range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Fault(10) As Boolean

For i = 1 To 10

If Range("A" & i).Value = "X" Then
    Fault(i) = True
End If

Next i


MsgBox Fault    'VBA Errors Here With "Type Mismatch"

End Sub
```

My question is, is it possible to return an entire array as a string. So in the above example, I want the message box to return "0000000000" if there were no faults. If there was a fault in the 7th array, then it would return "0000001000".

My aim is to check that the string is always equal to "0000000000" in order to proceed. However, if there's a better way of checking if the entire array is false then that would be much easier.

Comment: Is it essential to know where the fault occurred or is it sufficient just to know that there is a fault?

Comment: it would be best if I could know which bit of the array contained a `true` value, but I'm still interested in testing the entire array as a whole too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub JoinArray()
    Dim Fault(9) As String, arrString As String

    For i = 1 To 10
        If Range("A" & i) = "X" Then
            Fault(i - 1) = 1
        Else
            Fault(i - 1) = 0
        End If
    Next i

    arrString = Join(Fault(), "")

    If InStr(arrString, "1") Then
        MsgBox "Fault Found"
    Else
        MsgBox "No faults found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Notes:

1. Typically an array is zero indexed so `Fault(9)` allows for 10 slots e.g. Range("A1:A10")
2. The `""` argument of `Join` means there are no space in the output i.e. 0011000000

**Alternative method** without using an array

```
Sub FindFaults()
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range, faultLocations As String

    Set rng = Range("A1:A1000")
    faultLocations = "Faults found in the following cell(s):" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "X") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Fault Found"
    Else
        For Each cl In rng
            If cl = "X" Then
                faultLocations = faultLocations + "Cell: " & cl.Address & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next cl
    End If

    MsgBox faultLocations
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, but what if my `Fault` array was 1000 long? Obviously I don't want to test for "000000000...." to 1000. Is there a way to just test to make sure the entire Array is contains only "0", but if it doesnt, exactly where the 1's are located? Thanks for this answer though, its a step in the right direction

Comment: See update for how to see if any faults found. When you say where the 1s are located do you mean range references?

Comment: No, the `i` number will be OK

Comment: I'd prefer an Array, however if there's a simpler way it may suit better as long as the functionality is the same

Comment: See updated answer. Test for any `X` using `CountIf`. If found loop over the array and take a note of where the `X` are. Any good?

Comment: Thats great, thanks! Will be able to adjust this to fit with I want to do. Thanks very much!